# How to access self-hosted StackOverflow with StackAPI for Python

Tags: python-3.x, stackexchange-api

Is it possible to specify a self-hosted url?

```
from stackapi import StackAPI, StackAPIError
try:
    SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow.selfhosted-enterprise.com', proxy=proxies)
except StackAPIError as e:
    print(e.message)

ValueError: Invalid Site Name provided
```

According to https://stackapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html the `name` must be one of the sites on the Stack Exchange Network.
Also according to https://github.com/AWegnerGitHub/stackapi/blob/master/stackapi/stackapi.py#L70 it does not seem to allow for arbitrary urls, to cover the self-hosted / enterprise use case.

Is it possible to override it, or is there any other alternative for self-hosted / enterprise?

Comment: probably relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286827/stack-overflow-enterprise-api-support

Comment: thanks, I had checked the enterprise version - the API is available. I (am|was) hopeful I could use (the|an) existing Python wrapper around the API.